# Get a list of all selects which do not contain a option with a given value

Tags: javascript, jquery

By using jQuery, I'm trying to get jQuery to return all selects which do not contain a option with a given value, so far I have got:

```
$.each($("select:has(option:not(:contains('Stamp Duty 125k - 249k')))"), function (key, value) {
    $("p").text(value.name);
});
```

but this does not work if the select has more than one option. I've been struggling to find a way of doing the intended function, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()`

```
var $selects = $('select').filter(function(){
  var op = $('option',this).filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text())  === 'Stamp Duty 125k - 249k';
  });

  if(op.length > 0) return false;
  else return true;
});
```

You can use selects like this -

```
$selects.each(function (key, value) {
    $("p").append(value.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a copy paste error as you are missing the `$.each` method()

Your problem is mostly being caused becoz you are using `text` instead of `append` the replaces the  previous contents of the `p` .

```
$("select:has(option:not(:contains('Stamp Duty 125k - 249k')))").each(

function (key, value) {
    $("p").append(value.name);
});
```

Comment: youre missing the `.` in `each` :)